# find/make a time for something?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> -- Shall we go for a vacation?
>
> -- Let's __ a time for it.
>
> A. make B. find C. get D. fix

I narrow the answers down to "make" or "find", and I prefer "find", but there is "make an appointment". What do you think?

I also wonder if "time" can be used as a countable noun? I thought it was always uncountable. I would have said "let's find some time for it" instead. What would you think?

Thank!

Answer (score 4):

***finding*** a time implies that unallocated time was available and it just needed to be identified and allocated for your purpose.

***making*** a time implies that a deliberate decision was made to do something *instead* of other things.  That is, you *made* the time available by actively forgoing something else.

Comment: I edited my answer.  The question of whether it should be *a* time or just time is a second question only introduced in the last paragraph of the post.  But in answer:  *a* time should be used when the intent is to actually allocate *a specific* time slot on the calendar.  E.g., Let's find a time... how about between 3 and 4 on Thursday?   Just finding time refers to the desire to do something in the abstract but without a specific timeslot identified.

Comment: Wouldn't "make time for" more idiomatic? The question sounds as if to choose "find a time for sth." vs. "make time for sth.".

Comment: @DamkerngT.- they are both idiomatic and are used in slightly different situations as I've outlined in my comment above. If I say, "We should make time to go to the circus" I mean that I think it would be a good idea to go and that I think it would be worth rearranging our schedules in order to see them, if necessary. But that's more of just an abstract comment on how worthwhile I think the circus is.  But if I say, "We should make **a** time to go to see the circus," I'm implying that we should actually sit down and pick a time (and rearrange our schedules if necessary) to go see it.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, *make time* is idiomatic while *make a time* is not.  In COCA, I find 411 results for the former and only 11 for the latter; on inspection, all 11 are used in phrases where *time* is not the head noun, so all 11 are false positives.  In contrast, out of a random sampling of 100 out of the 411 results for *make time*, almost all were actual examples.

Comment: @snailboat- Here is an example of an actual usage I [found in ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22make%20a%20time%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en):  [*She had promised to call and make a time to see his garden...*](http://books.google.com/books?id=vgDzrFHPC5AC&pg=PA268&dq=%22make+a+time+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FKqkUu7-I-aoyAGbw4DwBg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22make%20a%20time%20to%22&f=false)  (Note there are two different links in this comment)

Answer (score 2):

1. I think much "make time" is more common than "make a time." I suspect most instances of "make a time" are coming from non-native speakers.
2. In fact, "fix a time" is quite common and in my opinion is the best answer to this question. ("Find time" is more common than "find a time" although the latter sounds better, but still quite wrong, than "make a time.") But "fix a time" works well when we use "time" as a count noun meaning "date."
3. The sentence "shall we go for a vacation" strikes me as excessively old-fashioned, but maybe it is just British. More commonly, at least in American English, one would say "Let's go on a vacation" or "Do you want to go on a vacation?"

Answer (score 1):

I think "fix a time" is the best answer because it covers more aspects of a vacation whereas other terms may imply an effect on *time* such as finances and logistics, which might not be relevant to both parties.

Comment: Rls -- Can you provide a little information about why you think this is true, and which English speakers are likely to agree with you?  For example, are you a native speaker?  Of which kind of English?